# Dropdown Menu to populate Form with Rails/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am going to do my best to describe this. What I am looking to do is populate a form with values based on a single dropdown. I want to take what the user selects in the dropdown, send a request to rails with the value they selected, do some stuff in a controller based on that selection and return an object back to the form with the fields filled in. Ideally I'd like to do this with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing on the frontend probably lends itself to and MVC or MVVM framework. I've used knockout.js for that with great success.

Basically you bind the properties of a JS "viewmodel" object to various elements in the markup. When the viewmodel changes, it automatically updates the markup, and vice versa. When you're ready to send it to your backend, use jQuery.post() to send back a serialized version of the viewmodel. The server can then respond with data that can be used to populate various fields in the viewmodel.